# i18next react Trans component - escaping characters correctly

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a react based application and use i18next's Trans component for translations.

Let's say we have a user registration form and we want to confirm that a new account has been created by displaying the following text:

> User with name **NAME** has been created.

where **NAME** is provided by user and is displayed in bold.

What I have now is the following code in react:

```
<Trans i18n={i18next} i18nKey="userCreated" values={{name: 'Tom'}}>
   User with name <strong>{{name}}</strong> has been created.
</Trans>
```

and the following translation string

```
"userCreated": "User with name <1>{{name}}</1> has been created.",
```

For a simple case with `name: 'Tom'` it works fine and displays

> User with name **Tom** has been created.

However I would like to let users use special characters in their names. When I change name to `Tom&Jerry` I'm getting

> User with name **`Tom&amp;Jerry`** has been created.

After doing some research I thought that the issue is that both i18next and react escape their inputs and so the name is escaped twice. I turned off the i18next escaping in `i18next.init` by adding the following option

`interpolation: {escapeValue: false},`

That fixes the Tom&Jerry case:

> User with name **Tom&Jerry** has been created.

but there are some inputs that break it completely, for example setting `name: 'Tom<'` renders like this (everything after name is bold):

> User with name **Tom has been created.**

and setting `name: '<Tom>'` gives me:

> User with name **has been created.**

(no name displayed at all). I would like it to render like this:

> User with name **`<Tom>`** has been created.

Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Can you provide the other react code? The other input component you think is escaping input?

Comment: @DrewReese I believe i18next is escaping it once - translating & into &amp; - and then react escapes it again so that instead of displaying a HTML entity &amp; is displayed literally. Turning off escaping in i18next fixes the issue, but then for some reason characters like < or > are breaking the whole functionality. There isn't much more react code, the Trans code I pasted is just rendered inside another component.

Comment: Ah, then this may be one of those rare instances where using react's [https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml](dangerouslysetinnerhtml) is valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no elegant solution to this problem. The root of the problem is in the source code of the `Trans` component. You either need to create a patch for this file changing this behavior or implement a cheaty trick by yourself. If you're going to use a cheaty solution, you'd create a component `UnescapedTrans` which will unescape HTML entities using lodash:

```
import React, { Suspense } from "react";
import { Trans } from "react-i18next";
import { unescape } from "lodash";


const getUnescapeChildrenRef = ref =>
  Array.from(ref.childNodes).forEach(node => {
    if (!node.innerText) {
      return node;
    }

    node.innerText = unescape(node.innerText);
  });

const UnescapedTrans = props => (
  <div ref={getUnescapeChildrenRef}>
    <Trans {...props} tOptions={{ interpolation: { escapeValue: true } }} />
  </div>
);
```

[CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/unescape-react-i18n-mr3pq).

Comment: Thank you, works great :-) To make it work in my webapp I had to add an additional nullcheck if(ref!=null) at the beginning of the code. I've also confirmed on github that the library doesn't handle that, but it should break only for <> chars so another option is to explicitly forbid/map them: https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/issues/964

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use `t()` of `useTranslation()` hook instead of `<Trans>` component,

```
const Component = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const label = t('this.is.your.key',
    'You {{ampersand}} Me',
    { ampersand: '&', interpolation: { escapeValue: false } }
  );
  return (<span>{label}</span>);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more elegant way to achieve this.

You can use property "**shouldUnescape**" of Trans component.
In my example the value for "welcome" is "<b>Special characters:</b> {{ characters }}"

```
import React from "react";
import { Trans } from "react-i18next";
import { escape } from "lodash";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Trans
        i18nKey="welcome"
        shouldUnescape={true}
        components={{ b: <b /> }}
        values={{ characters: escape("<, >, &") }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-i18next-forked-tn9c3k?file=/src/app.js

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make this work while setting `interpolation: { escapeValue: false }` globally (so that `t` still works as expected), by setting *both* `tOptions={{ interpolation: { escapeValue: true } }}` (so that values are escaped before interpolation) and `shouldUnescape` (so the whole translation string is unescaped after interpolation) on every `Trans` component:

```js
<Trans
 i18nKey="userCreated"
 values={{ name: 'Tom&Jerry <Tom><' }}
 tOptions={{ interpolation: { escapeValue: true } }}
 shouldUnescape
>
  User with name <strong>{{ name }}</strong> has been created.
</Trans>
```

[image]